# How do you get the next node in the document, as opposed to the next sibling?

Tags: javascript

in javascript, how do you get the next node in the dom as opposed to the next sibling? in xpath they have this.

take the following html for example:

```
<div>
  <p>
  <p id="current">
</div>
<div id="next">
  <p>
</div>
```

I want a function that when I run it on the node "current" it returns the node "next". I'm using the id's just for clarity.

Comment: If it had children, would the first child be the "next node"?

Comment: HTML is treated as a tree of elements. There's no "next node" once you've exhausted a particular set of a child nodes. (I get that this isn't really what you intend to ask.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say something like this could work, assuming `node` is the starting node.

```
while( !node.nextSibling && node.parentNode) node = node.parentNode;
node = node.nextSibling; // will be null if node was last in document
```

This will get the next node in the document - although I'm unsure if you count children as "subsequent" in this situation. If so, you should start with:

```
if( node.firstChild) node = node.nextChild;
else {
    while ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery would the following work:

```
function findNextNode(ElementToSearch) {
  if (ElementToSearch.next().length == 0) {
    return ElementToSearch.parent().next();
  } else {
    return ElementToSearch.next();
  }
}

var nextNode = findNextNode($('#current'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function next(current)
{
    var parent = current.parentNode,
        children = parent.children,
        //childNodes、nextSibling maybe contain ObjectText
        length = children.length;
    for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(current == children[i])
            break;
    }
    //if not lastChild
    if(i<length-1) 
    {
        return children[i+1];
    }
    else
    {
        //recursion search until parent == document.body
        if(parent != document.body)
        {
            return next(parent);
        }
        else
        {
            window.console.warn("Can not get next sibling");
        }
    }

}
```